# Script for clicking "Enter"

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

Can someone help me write a script so that when I hit CTRL and the RIGHT ALT key it's the same as me hitting the "Enter" key on Windows 7.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If this is the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key, it is awkward to do based on the fact this is registered as Left control + Right Alt... I can do enter if just this key is pressed:

```
LControl & RAlt::Send, {Enter}
```

That's as close as I can get... hopefully someone better than me at Auto Hot Key will come along soon, but perhaps this can push you in the right direction until then!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.  I think this is exactly what I am looking for.  The left CTRL and the right Alt.

Comment: @Carlos If it worked, mark as answer